# Creating a dynamic image via PHP within a block

Tags: media

I'm migrating a site from Drupal 5 to Drupal 8. 
The original D5 site has a page created by a PHP routine,  with an included dynamic image, created by a separate PHP routine. The page outputs HTML in the form:

```
    <img src="http://mysite/php/graph.php?f=myFileNameHere>
```

I've written a block to replace the original page, but am now stuck. How can I create the image in Drupal 8? There seems to be no way of just running any piece of PHP code, to produce any output, without first creating a page or block, and thus having loads of Drupal overhead.

Comment: _There seems to be no way of just running any piece of PHP code, to produce any output, without first creating a page or block, and thus having loads of Drupal overhead_ Yes that's correct, to use any framework you must integrate your code with it. There aren't any exceptions. If you want to create a file that just runs some arbitrary, standard php that doesn't need any Drupal functionality, there's nothing stopping you creating that file

Comment: _italic_ nothing stopping you creating that file. Indeed, I *have* created it - but I cant run it.

Comment: "nothing stopping you creating that file". Indeed, I *have* created it - but D8 will not allow me to run it. All it will do is display a 404 error.  That's the problem. If the code was on a separate web site, it would run OK.  All I can think of is to create a block that creates a physical file, then outputs the html for an IMG tag, with src="my newly created file.jpg". Seems OTT to me - I have about 2000 nodes that will need files creating. Or am I missng some way that a block can issue the JPG directly?